# How do I catch a query exception in laravel to see if it fails?

Tags: sql, laravel-5

All I'm trying to do is verify a query.

```
'SELECT * from table_that_does_not_exist'
```

Without that erroring out, I'd like to know it failed so I can return a response that states "Error: table does not exist" or the generic error.

Comment: If you're using `Eloquent` for your queries, you could use `firstOrFail()` on a `DB::raw()` query. Or a `try{ } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ }`

Comment: I tried the try catch however, it still shows the error.  For example:       

    try {
            $results = DB::connection('myDB')->select('BAD TEXT QUERY SHOULD FAIL');
        } catch ( Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
            // Don't do anything
        }

Comment: `try { $results = \DB::connection("example")->select(\DB::raw("SELECT * FROM unknown_table"))->first(); } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ die("Caught an error"); }` Throws and `dies` "Caught an error". Did you have the \ before Illuminate? I just realized I forgot that in my first comment. Also, you `$ex` would extend the base `Exception` class, so you can call `$ex->getMessage()` to return the exact error.

Comment: @TimLewis That was perfect thanks!  Feel free to add that as answer so I can reward you with a million dollars.

Comment: Haha no problem, will do!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The simplest way to catch any `sql` syntax or query errors is to catch an `Illuminate\Database\QueryException` after providing closure to your query:

```
try { 
  $results = \DB::connection("example")
    ->select(\DB::raw("SELECT * FROM unknown_table"))
    ->first(); 
    // Closures include ->first(), ->get(), ->pluck(), etc.
} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ 
  dd($ex->getMessage()); 
  // Note any method of class PDOException can be called on $ex.
}
```

If there are any errors, the program will `die(var_dump(...))` whatever it needs to.

Note: For namespacing, you need to first `\` if the class is not included as a `use` statement.

Also for reference:

[Laravel 5.5 API - Query Exception](http://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html)

[Laravel 8.x API - Query Exception](http://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html)

Comment: For Laravel 5.5 this answer doesn't work for me. Please refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881563/when-calling-dbselect-why-do-i-get-a-the-connection-was-reset-message

Comment: In my case sometime mysql server goes down, we are working to fix though. IN the meantime, how to handle this connection error showing (SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user) explicitly and show soft error message?

Comment: @Butterfly That's beyond the scope of this question. Try searching Stackoverflow for that error, or ask a new question.

Comment: Reference link is broken, this one works:
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html

Comment: @AsafM Thanks for that! Looks like they retired the Laravel 5.1 API; your link, or https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html are both acceptable. Will update answer. Cheers!

Comment: Worked for Lumen 8, thanks! I was using just `Exception` which didn't catch `QueryException`, now when specified `\Illuminate\Database\QueryException` it captures it!

Answer (score 24):

Wrap the lines of code you wish to catch an exception on using try-catch statements

```
try
{
//write your codes here
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

Do not forget to include the Exception class at the top of your controller by saying

```
Use Exception;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, I didn't have use Exception at the top of my controller file but wasn't getting an error when trying to use it. Thanks a million!

Comment: Welcome Alex, I am glad that helped.

Comment: or just use backslash before exception so it doesn't need to "Use Exception;" : catch(\Exception $e)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to catch all types of database exceptions you can catch it on laravel `Exception Handler`

```
if ($exception instanceof \PDOException) {
    # render a custom error
}
```

for more details about how to use laravel `Exception Handler` check https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors

Comment: Please really should upvote this. Best answer by far, thanks!

Comment: [reference link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors) for detailed documentation, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks Ashraf , that is very helpful. Example in app/Exceptions/Handler.php :     
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof \PDOException) {
            dd("Error connecting to database, please turn on MySQL database server");
        }
        parent::report($exception);
    }

Answer (score 6):

**Laravel 8.x**

```
    try {
        $model->save(); // Use Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        return 'My error message';
    }
```

Note* Need to specify `\Throwable $e` no `Throwable $e`.