# When calling DB::select why do I get a "The connection was reset" message?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.5 application, calls to DB::select which run a select query on a Postgresql database fail without showing any error in the Apache or Laravel error logs and trigger a "The connection was reset" message. This code sample runs as expected because the function `get_users_with_roles` exists.

```
public function missing_function(Request $request) {
        try{
           $all = DB::select('SELECT * from get_users_with_roles()', []);
        }catch(Illuminate\Database\QueryException $qe){
            return json_encode($qe->getMessage());
        }
        return json_encode($all);
}
```

However, if I replace that SQL string with a function that doesn't exist:

```
public function missing_function(Request $request) {
        try{
           $all = DB::select('SELECT * from test()', []);
        }catch(Illuminate\Database\QueryException $qe){
            return json_encode($qe->getMessage());
        }
        return json_encode($all);
}
```

The connection is reset and I can't see any errors in the logs. If I run this erroneous query in a native Postgresql environment:

```
SELECT * from test();
```

I get a clear error message:

```
    ERROR:  function test() does not exist
LINE 1: select * from test()
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

It is particularly strange because this problem is not consistent. The try block sometimes catches the QueryException and displays the Postgresql error message as excepted.

I have tried adding

```
php_flag xcache.cacher Off 
php_flag xcache.size 0 
php_flag xcache.stat Off
```

to the .htaccess file but to no avail.

I need the ability to use the DB::select method because I rely heavily on Postgresql user-defined SQL and plpgsql functions in the application. I have a function which constructs the relevant SQL and passes it the DB::select method programmatically, so I need to be able to catch exceptions thrown when there is an error in the SQL, such as when the function is missing.

**UPDATE**

This problem seems to be with the way DB::select handles any SQL error. I've just tried this out with a function which exists but which throws an SQL error. Again, instead of allowing me to catch this in PHP with a try/catch block, it just resets the connection and doesn't log an error in either the Laravel log or the Apache log.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679996/how-do-i-catch-a-query-exception-in-laravel-to-see-if-it-fails/33681273) doesn't shed any light. The accepted answer there refers to the expected behaviour. In my environment, the QueryException isn't thrown or caught.

Comment: What does `$all` contain when the exception is not thrown?

Comment: Have you tried catching `\Throwable` (instead of `QueryException`) to see if maybe another exception is being thrown, and then later swallowed by another handler in your application?

Comment: $all contains whatever the select statement returns. In this case, it returns a table as an array of objects, but I have other examples where I'm just returning a scalar value. However, I have the same problem of not being able to catch the sql error if it doesn't return.

Comment: I tried catching \Throwable but there was no change.

Comment: So you're saying, this code `$all = DB::select('SELECT * from test()', []);`  produces an `$all` that contains an array of objects, even though `test` purportedly does not exist?

Comment: No. `$all = DB::select('SELECT * from get_users_with_roles()', []);` succeeds as expected. When I change the SQL to one that triggers an error in Postgresql, the Laravel try/catch block doesn't catch the exception. The function test() doesn't exist so it triggers an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169483/discussion-between-bishop-and-davidhyogo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tricky part of this has been the browser's stubborn refusal to reveal any form of error message. When that happens, I like to go to the command line and try it, thus eliminating the web server as a variable.

From chat, we learned that the command line showed the error as expected, but did not gracefully do so: the error was output, and the script was halted. That's a hard crash, one not attributable to the web server.

With the introduction of `\Throwable`, the scenarios where PHP dies hard are becoming fewer and farther between. So, in an effort to catch PHP's dying breath, we implemented a `register_shutdown_function` that pulled `error_get_last` in an effort to figure out what, if anything, was said just before blowing up.

This revealed, briefly, the error message in the browser (this time using a different browser). However, this was not repeatable. The insight at this point was caching: `composer dump-autoload` fixed the problem!

I suspect what happened is this:

- `Eloquent` threw an exception
- PHP was bubbling that up through Laravel's exception handling classes
- At some point, PHP attempted to load a class that wasn't in the autoloader
- PHP crashed hard (this is one of those cases where PHP 7.0 bails)

By running `composer dump-autoload`, all the "missing" classes were brought into the autoloader's purview and, when tried again, the correct code sequence happened.

Comment: Please check my latest question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130437/laravel-5-5-why-is-exception-not-thrown-by-foreign-key-violation-from-delete-met The problem is back and is even more intractable. As I type, I am upgrading to PHP 7.3 and Laravel 5.7 in the vain hope of throwing exceptions when expected!

Answer (score -2):

i think its an Sql query error

```
 `SELECT * from test()`
```

Since () bracket indicates the function so try to use like

```
 `SELECT * from test` in your query
```

Best way in laravel

## Create a model with php artisan make:model Test

Then use in controller like

```
     `use App\Test;'
```

and then to fetch records
`Test::all();`
it  will bring all records from database like your requirement SELECT * from Test

Comment: Jay, I know it’s an SQL error. I deliberately triggered it for test purposes. As I explained in my question, I rely on Postgres functions so I need to use DB::select with raw SQL. Laravel’s Eloquent model works with tables, not functions. Please read the answer I awarded the bonus to. I’m forced to downvote you because you misunderstood the question.