# How to handle Query Exception in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm looking for any way to handle the `QueryException`  using the laravel framework.

Is there any possible way to prevent the usual user from getting such an error with a handler?

I tried to prevent that black detailed error page not to be visible to any user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I catch a query exception in laravel to see if it fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679996/how-do-i-catch-a-query-exception-in-laravel-to-see-if-it-fails)

Comment: @  s.wadhwa yes it does work. But I'm looking for something to be applied to all functions.

Comment: Set `APP_DEBUG` to `false` in the `.env` file

Comment: You can also look the Ashraf Hefny answer in the question provided by s.wadhwa to apply it to all functions.

Comment: There's a whole [section in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors) on error handling.  I suggest you take a look at that as well, but most important is setting APP_DEBUG to false for non development environments.

Comment: Thanks, guys! ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch an exception on using **`try-catch`** statements :

```
Use Exception;

try
{
   // write your codes here
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
   //dd($e->getMessage());
   return "Something Went Wrong";
}
```

If you want to catch `PDO Exception` :

```
use PDOException;

try
{
   //write your codes here
} 
catch(\PDOException $e)
{
   //dd($e->getMessage());
   return "Something Went Wrong":
}
```