# Cannot catch QueryException in Laravel

Tags: laravel, exception, eloquent, illuminate

I'm trying to catch a `QueryException` error in a `try/catch` block. I'm running a `migrate:fresh` command from the terminal and setting some config values. I want to rule out some exceptions and catch this error if it appears. I tried everything but could not seem to succeed.

**Command**

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

**Error**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException   SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:
> database "x" does not exist (SQL: select tablename from
> pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemana*me in ('public'))

**Code**

```
try {
    DB::purge('pgsql');
    Config::set('database.connections.pgsql.database', $config['database']);
    Config::set('database.connections.pgsql.username', $config['username']);
    Config::set('database.connections.pgsql.password', $config['password']);
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    dd($e); //it never gets here
    Log::error($e->getMessage());
}
```

**I also tried**

```
catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) 
catch (\Exception $e)
catch (\PDOException $e)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is the exception thrown in `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`? How does the rest of the code relate to that?

Comment: have you tried `catch (\QueryException $e)` ?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65780158/4575350

Comment: The command triggers a function in which I have the try/catch block. I tried both \QueryException and \PDOException.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying, I managed to catch the error.
The $this->laravel->call([$this, 'handle']) was in another class and this is where the try/catch block should actually be.